# How to render HTML tags in admin product grid, Magento2.3?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I'm trying to make an anchor link in the product grid view.

I have tried this using UI component, below are the detailed view

xml code:

```
<column name="column_name" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\link">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

datasource code:

```
 $html = '<a href="my_linK.html" target="_blank">'. __('Label').'</a>';
 $item[$this->getData('name')] = $html;
```

Getting html like this:  `<a href="my_linl.html" target="_blank">Label</a>`
I want 'Label' with the anchor link.

Comment: What error you are getting after implementing this?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, it is just displaying the html "<a href="my_linl.html" target="_blank">Label</a>" as it is in the grid.

Comment: Is there anything I'm missing out of this?

Comment: Please follow the below link to achieve that. [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188059/rendering-a-html-tag-in-grid-magento-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188059/rendering-a-html-tag-in-grid-magento-2)